# Finding the work using integrals

Tags: integration, applications, volume

A tank full of water has the shape obtained by revolving the curve $y = arcsin(x)$ around the y axis
from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. Find the work required to pump the water out of the tank. (The density of water
is $1000$ kg /
m$^3$ ).

I know I have to use integration to solve the problem, but I don't know anything other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the work involved in pumping a cross-sectional element of the water is

$$\pi \rho g x^2(y) (1-y) dy$$

where $x(y) = \sin{y}$.  $\rho$ is the density and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity.  $1-y$ is the distance needed to raise the element to pump it out of the tank.  The the total work involved is

$$\pi \rho g  \int_0^1 dy \, (1-y) \sin^2{y} $$

This integral may be done using integration by parts.  The result is that the work is

$$\frac{\pi}{4} \rho g \cos^2{(1)}$$